# how to solve integrals involving derivative of delta function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

How to solve this kind of integrals?
$$
I=\int dx\int dx_1   f(x)g(x_1) \bigg[\frac{d \delta (x-x_1)}{d(x-x_1)}\bigg]
$$
here $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions. The derivative is w.r.t. difference of $x$ and $x_1$

Comment: Integration by parts should work.

Comment: @Andrei thanks for the comment. integration by part is $\int u dv = uv - \int v du$. I am confused that what value should I take as $u$, and $dv$ because in my case, $x$ and $x_1$ are entangled in delta function and its derivative

Comment: Change of variables first

Comment: @Andrei I have done this derivation and I get zero answer. I have written it as an answer to this question, could you please have a look at this

Answer (score 1):

First put $y = x-x_1$, we get:
$$
I=\int d(y+x_1) \bigg(\int dx_1   f(y+x_1)g(x_1) \bigg[\frac{d \delta (y)}{dy}\bigg]\bigg)
$$
For the inner integraion, use integration by parts $\int u dv = uv-\int vdu $. Let $u = f(y+x_1)g(x_1) $, and $dv = dx_1 \bigg[\frac{d \delta (y)}{dy}\bigg]$. And we get $du =  dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(y+x_1)g(x_1)]$, and $v=\delta(y)$. So, the inner integral become:
$$
f(y+x_1)g(x_1)\delta(y) - \int dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(y+x_1)g(x_1)] \delta (y)
$$
put the value of $y$:
$$
f(x)g(x_1)\delta(x-x_1) - \int dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(x)g(x_1)] \delta (x-x_1)
$$
So, the total integral is:
$$
I=\int dx \bigg(f(x)g(x_1)\delta(x-x_1) - \int dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(x)g(x_1)] \delta (x-x_1)\bigg) \\
I=\int dx f(x)g(x_1)\delta(x-x_1) - \int dx \int dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(x)g(x_1)] \delta (x-x_1) \\
I=f(x_1)g(x_1)- \int dx_1 \frac{d}{dx_1}[f(x_1)g(x_1)]\\
 I=f(x_1)g(x_1)- f(x_1)g(x_1)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int dx\int dx_1 \, f(x) g(x_1) \delta'(x-x_1)
= \{ y := x-x_1 \}
= \int dy \int dx_1 \, f(y+x_1) g(x_1) \delta'(y)
\\
= \int dx_1 \left( \int dy \, f(y+x_1) \delta'(y) \right) g(x_1)
= \int dx_1 \left( -\int dy \, f'(y+x_1) \delta(y) \right) g(x_1)
\\
= - \int dx_1 \, f'(x_1) g(x_1)
$$